# Provide an example if possible

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an example such that $$\left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x_n \right) \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty y_n \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x_n y_n$$ where $x_n$ and $y_n$ have nonzero terms for all $n$.

Comment: you should presumably add "with everything converging absolutely"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$x_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\frac1{(n+1)^2} & x\mbox{ even} \\
-\frac1{n^2} & x\mbox{ odd} \\
\end{array} \right.$$
and let $y_n = 1$ for all $n$.

The $\sum x_n$ converges (absolutely) to zero, as does $\sum x_n y_n$.

So this is your example, with $0=0$.

**EDIT**

A better $y_n$ to use in the example is $y_n = x_n$, because then $\sum y_n$ converges and you don't have to fret about $0\times \infty$.

Comment: see my comment above - I'm not sure that this example will please the OP...

Comment: well, cough, so much for my thoughts....

Comment: What is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$?

Comment: @robjohn RIght, I should change it to something that converges.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is to take geometric series. For example, I think:
$$
x_n = \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^n \\
y_n = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^n
$$
works.

Comment: $-\frac12$ and $\frac14$ can be replaced by $a$ and $b$ where $(2a-1)(2b-1)=1$ and $-1\lt a,b\lt1$.

Answer (score 1):

**In General**

The equation
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_ny_n\tag{1}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
y_0\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\right)\tag{2}
$$
Thus, as long as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n\ne0$, we can take any $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ then compute $y_0$ from $(2)$.

---

**Example $\boldsymbol{1}$**

If we let $x_n=2^{-n}$ for all $n\ge0$ and $y_n=2^{-n}$ for all $n\ge1$ and $y_0=-\frac53$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_ny_n=-\frac43\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Example $\boldsymbol{2}$**

If we let $x_n=5^{-n}$ for all $n\ge0$ and $y_n=(-3)^{-n}$ for all $n\ge0$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_ny_n=\frac{15}{16}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$